# Spring data JPA populate data of 2 One-To-Many relationship

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a ManyToMany relationship that is broken down into 2 OneToMany relation. A Book can belong to multiple Categories and a Category can have many Books.
When I query for Book, the `categories` list just get empty. How can I get a list of all Categories that a Book belong to ? Am I missing something ?

```
@Entity
public class Book {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  @NotBlank(message = "Please input book title")
  private String title;

  private Integer publishYear;

  private String publisher;

  private String language;

  private Integer numberOfPages;

  private String avatarUrl;

  @OneToMany(targetEntity = BookCategory.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "category", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Set<BookCategory> categories = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class Category {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  @NotBlank(message = "Please input category name")
  private String name;
}

@Entity
public class BookCategory {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "book", nullable = false)
  private Book book;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "category", nullable = false)
  private Category category;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mappedBy` attribute with @OneTOMany annotation on the 'One' side of the OneToMany relation.

Or you can also try using the following:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
  name = “book”_category, 
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = “book_id”), 
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = “category_id))
```

Read more:
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/